# How to add column that might include the column itself information?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a series of number as below, and I want to add "flag" for every cumulative value greater than 10.

The cumulative value will reset to 0 once cumulative value reach 10 and flag as 1.

```
row  number  FLAG
1     5        0  
2     4        0
3     9        1  =>cumulative value=5+4+9=18>10, so flag as 1. and reset the cumulative value.
4     8        0
5     8        1  =>cumulative value=8+8=16>10, so flag as 1. and reset the cumulative value.
6     7        0
7     1        0
8     4        1 =>cumulative value=7+1+4>10, so flag as 1. and reset the cumulative value.
9     5        0
10    4        0
```

Any idea is appreciated!

lag function doesn't help...

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: The task is iterative. So recursive query or iterative stored procedure must be used. On version 5.x the user-defined variable can be used.

Comment: Since you will be inserting new data. You should not be doing it with SQL. Do it with the programming language. Because you will need the id to effect the calculation on a single row, but you are yet to insert the data